# Bad Request RestSharp Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, web-services, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I've been trying to make a WCF web service that enters a certain set of data into a database and it can be used in Windows Phone 7. In the configuration file there are two endpoints: json and soap. Here's the code for both of them:

```
<service name="LiveAndesWCF.SightingServiceRest" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="LiveAndesWCF.ISightingServiceRest"/>
    <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="LiveAndesWCF.ISightingServiceRest"/>
</service>
...
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="76384000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
                <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="76384000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Now, I deployed the service to a server, downloaded its metadata with slsvcutil.exe and stored both the code file and the ServiceReferenceConfig file in the project. Now, the slsvcutil only generates the configuration for the soap endpoint.

Now, I try to use the service using the [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) library, by using the following code:

```
public static void sendSighting()
{
    string URL = "http://liveandesor.web711.discountasp.net/wcf/SightingServiceRest.svc/json/SaveNewSightingRest";

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    var client = new RestClient(URL);

    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Host", "liveandesor.web711.discountasp.net");
    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    JObject json = new JObject();

    json.Add("UserId", "letroll");
    json.Add("Location", "TEST");
    json.Add("Longitude", 50);
    json.Add("Latitude", 50);
    json.Add("Comment", "TEST");
    json.Add("SpeciesId", 438);
    json.Add("_Date", new DateTime(2011, 8, 12));
    json.Add("DateString", (new DateTime(2011, 8, 12)).ToString());
    json.Add("SightingTypeId", 1);
    json.Add("Quantity", 1);
    json.Add("AgeId", 1);
    json.Add("SexId", 1);
    json.Add("PhotoURL", new JArray(new List<String>()));
    json.Add("Request", false);
    json.Add("Visibility", false);
    json.Add("SightingStateId", 1);
    json.Add("Created_at", new DateTime());
    json.Add("Updated_at", new DateTime());

    String jason = json.ToString();

    try
    {
        //request.AddObject(json);
        request.AddBody(jason);

        RestResponse resource;

        client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
        {
            resource = response;
            string content = resource.Content;
            string status_code = resource.StatusCode.ToString();
            string response_status = resource.ResponseStatus.ToString();
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string error = "Error: " + e.ToString() + "\n. Stack Trace: " + e.StackTrace;
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

If I try to use the URL given in the sample code, I get an "endpoint not found" error, which is to be expected. However, if I try to use the SOAP endpoint via the URL http://liveandesor.web711.discountasp.net/wcf/SightingServiceRest.svc/soap/SaveNewSightingRest, I just get a "Bad Request" status code.

Why does this happen? Is there any way I can make it work? If it can be any helpful, everytime I click on the link I provided for the SOAP service I just get a blank screen.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It appears the problem lies in the service itself, because I try to access the endpoint via a URL request but it throws a 400 Bad Request error. :(

Comment: I'll do it right now and add it to the edit on the original question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't have to post in comments:

What does your body look like in fiddler, with RestSharp you can create a poco and simply, `RestRequest.AddBody(MyPoco);`

I think the url:

```
 string URL = "http://liveandesor.web711.discountasp.net/wcf/SightingServiceRest.svc/json/SaveNewSightingRest";
```

should be:

```
string URL = "http://liveandesor.web711.discountasp.net/wcf/SightingServiceRest.svc";
```

and then:

```
RestRequest.Resource = "json/SaveNewSightingRest";
```

update:
I copied your code, chanding the url/resource and in fiddler the body is: `<String />`  To clarify, this is the body being sent, so you'd expect to see the json you're trying to send.

with error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'String' and
>   root namespace '' (for operation 'SaveNewSightingRest' and contract
>   ('ISightingServiceRest', 'http://tempuri.org/')) using
>   DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the type corresponding to the XML
>   is added to the known types collection of the service.

Comment: Derek: This was exactly what I needed!! I had an error on the way I was sending the information to the server, specifically with an empty String array. Anyways, I can't tell you how much you've helped. I've been literally all day long searching for an answer. Thank you so much!! :D